# php/mysql search function issue

Tags: php, mysql, database, function, search

I feel like I just need another set of eyes on this. There is of course something in the database to search, however nothing is displayed. Is there something wrong with the syntax or logic. This is all in one file index.php

```
    <form action = "index.php" method = "post">
 Search: <input type="text" name="value" placeholder="Is it part of the FWO?"></input>
  <input type=submit name = "search" value="Search">
    </form> 

  <a href="LINKY">New Entry</a>
  <br>
  <p>Search Results</p>
  <hr /> 


  <?php
       error_reporting(E_ALL);
       $title = $_POST['value'];
       echo "You have searched: " .$title;
       echo "<br>";

       $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die ('Could not connect, this is the error:  ' . mysql_error());
       mysql_select_db("db") or die ('Sorry could not access database at this time.  This is the error:  ' . mysql_error());   

       $clean = msql_real_escape_string($_GET['value']);
       echo "Another test ". $clean;
       $run = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db WHERE name = '$clean'") or die(mysql_error());

       if(mysql_num_rows($run) >= 1){
        echo "found entry";
        while($i = mysql_fetch_array($run)){
            echo $i['creator'];
        }

       }

       else {
        echo "No entries found";
       }


       mysql_close($con);
?>



  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Is your value a POST or a GET value, because you use both of them

Comment: in place of $_GET, you should use $_POST

Comment: Change this $clean = msql_real_escape_string($_GET['value']); to $clean = msql_real_escape_string($title);

Comment: Did you create `msql_real_escape_string`? Are you checking your error logs? When you say `nothing is displayed` do you mean you get a blank page or no search results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form is using post method and you are trying get a value by $_GET

instead of this:

```
$clean = msql_real_escape_string($_GET['value']);
```

Use this:

```
$clean = msql_real_escape_string($_POST['value']);
```

Or

```
$clean = msql_real_escape_string($title);
```

Answer (score 0):

To search inside mysql you should use LIKE. and if you want to search anywhere in the string you should encapsulate with %. for example:

```
   $run = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db WHERE name LIKE '%$clean%'") or die(mysql_error());
```

for more info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html